# Open source products like ExtJs Gui Designer

Tags: open-source, web-development, wysiwyg

I would like to dynamically build my maintenance (CRUD) webpages from a repository. The UI definitions should in the end come from a DB at the backend.

Are there (not totally outdated) open source WYSIWYG editors for webpages that store UI definitions in XML or JSON?

Like ExtJs Gui Designer (http://extjs.org.cn/ux/GuiDesigner/ sources: http://extjs.org.cn/node/298)

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Answer (score 1):

[Maqetta](http://maqetta.org) is an open source technology initiative at Dojo Foundation that provides WYSIWYG visual authoring of HTML5 user interfaces for HTML5 (desktop and mobile):

[image: Maquetta GUI]

Maquetta self is a pure, single-page JS application written in Maquetta, too.

[Dojo](https://dojotoolkit.org/) is a Javascript framework using HTML5 markup extended by XML to define the GUI elements. More clearly, you can construct the GUI visually, and finetuning it with CSS and positioning HTML5 tags:

[image: Dojo source screenshot]

Dojo has AJAX support as well, but the binding of the GUI events to the CRUD operations will be your task (not really complex task). For single-page JS apps it is a perfect solution, especially because dojo uses the [AMD](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition) (asynchronous module definition) class-loading javascript paradighm to load its modules (and sub-modules) on the need, asynchronously, by ajax.

On my experience, Dojo and Dojo-based solutions are quite common by big German companies.